# IF-ELSE Return Value Output is Incorrect: Using Comparison Operator [SOLVED: Comparison of 'np.nan == np.nan' is not Recommended]

Tags: python, pandas

Incorrect output value when `x == math.nan`; I've also tried using `if (math.isnan(x) is True):` as condition. Instead of returning `True` I get `NaN`. Can I know the reason for this occurence?

**Input:**

```
import math
def nan_impute(x):
    if (x == math.nan):
        return True
    else:
        return False

train_data['country_2'] = train_data.loc[:,'country'].apply(nan_impute)

train_data
```

**Output:**

[image]

Comment: why not just use `train_data['country_2']=train_data['country'].isna()` apply is not required for such cases. Also `math.nan==math.nan` returns `False` so that comparision fails

Comment: Thanks sir :) I keep better understanding the meaning 'nan' and 'None' with every passing day. Thanks a ton!

Comment: try `def nan_imputer(x): return x != x`

Answer (score 1):

I think you may want @anky_91 says:

```
train_data['country2'] = train_data['country'].isna()
```

---

However,

`np.nan != np.nan` returns `True` in python. As @Vishal points out.

Try:

```
import math
def nan_impute(x):
    if (x != x):
        return True
    else:
        return False

train_data['country_2'] = train_data.loc[:,'country'].apply(nan_impute)

train_data
```

Answer (score 0):

Having understood more about `np.nan, math.nan`, it is **not** recommended to ever have to compare *missing values* or *NaN - Not a Number* value(s).

Peculiarities:

```
x = np.nan
print(x == np.nan)
#Returns 'False'
```

If needed to check if a value is `NaN`, use:

```
np.isnan(x)
#True
import math
math.isnan(x)
#True
```

For Checking within Columns in Dataframe:

```
x_1 = pd.DataFrame({'c_1': [1,2,np.nan, 5,np.nan]})
x_1['nan_checker'] = x_1['c_1'].isna()
x_1
```

**Output:**

[image]